# Issue With BufferedReader

Tags: java, url, web-crawler, bufferedreader

I am creating a web crawler that crawls through .edu domains. At the moment, my program reads from command line a seed file that contains url of many .edu and other parameters. As I read in each url from the file, I then pass the url to a different function that download the contents of the page. When I just pass in one url, everything works fine. However, when I send in multiple files, my program gets stuck after I open the input stream of the URL contents.

The two parameters are coming from my function (readFromSeedFile) that just opens seed.txt and a reads the url line by line and then calls downloadFile.

```
  public static void downloadFile(String seed, int i) throws IOException, MalformedURLException{

    System.out.println("In downloadFile");
    URL urlObj = new URL(seed);
    System.out.println("1");
    BufferedReader x = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlObj.openConnection().getInputStream()));
    System.out.println("2");
    String fileName = "file" + i + ".html";
    System.out.println("3");
    BufferedWriter fos = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
    System.out.println("4");
    while(x.ready()){
      System.out.println("while loop of downloadFile");
      String line = x.readLine();
      fos.write(line);
      fos.write("\n");
    }
    x.close();
    fos.close();

  }
```

It throws the IO Exception that I have in place in ReadFromSeedFile. 
This is the error message that I get

```
S$ javac WebCrawler.java 
S$ java WebCrawler seed.txt 3 4 out.txt
while loop of readSeedFile
http://cs.ucr.edu/
In downloadFile
1
Exception occurred trying to read 'seed.txt'.
```

Is there something with BufferedReader that I am not understanding?

Comment: Use `try`/`catch` to catch the exception.  Then, print the exception (using for example, [printStackTrace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace())) and tell us what the details of the exception are.

Comment: Note that `System.out` is buffered by default, so it's generally not a good idea to use it for debugging. Instead, use `System.err` or, better get, a logger

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong, but the link http://cs.ucr.edu/ isn't reachable! This is a possible error, you have to work with timers.